# Gostaria de conectar rails ao Intel xdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intel

Meu objetivo final é  criar um app no xdk que interaja com o rails. Se ninguém souber exatamente como funciona mas der uma luz de como acessar o sqlite com ruby e javascript já ajuda muito. Tenho algumas dúvidas da maneira correta de se fazer isso. Por exemplo o ideal é criar um initialize no rails? Não posso acessar só com javascript por causa da segurança certo? Existe gem para isso? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é você criar uma `API REST` com o `rails` , utilizando por exemplo a [gem grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape), e consumir esses dados via `JSON` na sua aplicação `Intel XDK`.

Quanto a questão de segurança será necessário que vc configure os [CORS](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#cors) no `rails` para ele permitir acesso externo. No exemplo do link ele permite acesso apenas via `get` mas vc pode implementar os outros métodos `put, delete, post`....